# Django Migration is not apply new migrations

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I tried to make new migrations but show me error. I am using django1.9 and python 2.7 .Is any solution for this so i can create new migration.How can I do the migration?

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "appointments_userappointments_advance_c37857a7_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (advance, status)=(5000, 3) is duplicated.
```

Here is my model:

```
class UserAppointments(models.Model):
    """
    Represent an Appointment entity

    """

    STATUS = (
        ("1", 'Scheduled'),
        ("2", 'Active'),
        ("3", 'Completed'),
        ("4", 'Cancelled')
    )

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, blank=True)
    staff_user = models.ForeignKey(StaffUser, null=True, blank=True, related_name='staff_user')
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, blank=True)
    advance = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(StaffUser, null=True, blank=True, related_name='created_by')
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(StaffUser, null=True, blank=True, related_name='updated_by')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, default=1, choices=STATUS)
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Appointments'
    ordering = ['date_time']

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.date_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

and my migration file:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('appointments', '0009_auto_20180114_1838'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelOptions(
            name='userappointments',
            options={'ordering': ['advance'], 'verbose_name_plural': 'Appointments'},
        ),
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name='userappointments',
            unique_together=set([('advance', 'status')]),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: If you can try to delete and recreate the database other then delete all migrations files and try to migrate again

Comment: @alessioferri20 this is not solution. i have soo many changes.

Comment: There is still the file: '0010_auto_20180117_1240'? @zeeshan

Comment: Try to follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27650735/9202856

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem here is that this is a unique together index. So you have at least 2 rows in your database that share the same values for the fields. Thus because the uniqueness guarantee has been violated it cannot great the composite unique index.

You may wish to consider using regular composite indexes.

Please see these docs for examples: [django indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#indexes)