# How to apply django initial migration?

Tags: python, django

`showmigrations` shows that there is 31 available migrations:

```
# python3 manage.py showmigrations
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20190114_1409
 [X] 0003_auto_20190114_1410
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_auto_20190114_1409
authtoken
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20160226_1747
 [X] 0003_auto_20190114_1409
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
 [X] 0003_auto_20190114_1409
exchange_delivery
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_enlarge_phone_field
 [X] 0003_unique_external_id
 [X] 0004_add_warehouse
 [X] 0005_add_delivery_point_type
 [X] 0006_update_delivery_type_operating_mode
 [X] 0007_add_delivery_point_region_model
 [X] 0008_update_warehouse_exchange
 [X] 0009_add_verbose_name_for_warehouse_and_add_delivery_point_banned_group
 [X] 0010_add_active_flag_to_warehouse
 [X] 0011_auto_20190114_1409
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20190114_1410
volt
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20190114_1410
```

How to apply all this migrations ?  `migrate` shows that `No migrations to apply`

```
# python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: corsheaders, export, opinion, volt.integration1c.delivery, custom_logger, event_listener, legacy, region, order, catalog, promo_table, messages, staticfiles, api, best_product, shop, general, market_cpa, rest_framework, delivery, exchange, talk
  Apply all migrations: auth, authtoken, sessions, exchange_delivery, admin, volt, contenttypes
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py:239: RemovedInDjango19Warning: initial_data fixtures are deprecated. Use data migrations instead.
  RemovedInDjango19Warning

Installed 0 object(s) (of 6) from 1 fixture(s)
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

I'm not familiar with Django, I need just dockerize existing app.

As far as I understand from output of `python3 manage.py syncdb` command

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table '220-django.auth_user' doesn't exist")
```

Problem is that initial migrations for django and django-admin are not applied

Project is under `Django 1.8.14`

Comment: Try using `python3 manage.py migrate app_name` for the base app. Replace app_name with your base app.

Comment: try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27650735/5372300)

Comment: @Sam, how to define base app ? I have 5 top level apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` at `general/settings.py`

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, all the migrations has **[X]** beside their names. Means these migrations are already applied, [as per documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#showmigrations). If there is any un-applied migrations, then it will show up as **[ ]** beside the name of the migration. For more details(if the migrations has been applied or not), please check the `django_migrations` table in DB.

Comment: Is it possible that [X] is result of fake migration and `showmigrations` migrations are not applied in fact? I added strange output of `python3 manage.py syncdb` to question

Comment: Yes, if you fake apply a migration, it will show `[X]` as there has been an entry made in `django_migrations` table.

Comment: I don't know why you want to use `syncdb`. its depricated and just replicates `python manage.py migrate`. I think you can look into this repo regarding dockerizing django: https://github.com/ruddra/docker-django

Comment: Thank you for link to repo! I checked database 220-django on production, it has following tables https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zDSfjPC44G/ Could you please tell me, is it standart Django tables ?

Comment: Yes. They are standard table for a django project with default apps.

Comment: BTW, please keep in mind that django 1.8 has no official support now. Consider upgrading to 1.11 or 2.X

Answer (score 0):

You have some entries in `django_migrations` table in your database so that migrate shows `No migrations to apply`.
To solve this, goto database console and run the following command

```
delete from django_migrations;
```

**Or**, directly go to the database table and delete all rows.

Then run

```
python manage.py migrate
```