# Troubles with adding migrations on Heroku , Django app

Tags: django, heroku, django-migrations, heroku-postgres

I ran into a problem with migration on Heroku. I made few model changes locally, migrated it smoothly locally as well – no problems. When I re-deployed my app on Heroku (app was already there with old pre-migration DB) and ran migrations I got following output:

```
python manage.py makemigrations on ⬢ boatsproject-eu... up, run.2252 (Free)
Migrations for 'articles':
  articles/migrations/0018_auto_20190613_1240.py
    - Add field change_date to comment
    - Add field change_date to heading
    - Alter field change_date on article
    - Alter field title on article
    - Alter field author on comment
Migrations for 'boats':
  boats/migrations/0028_auto_20190613_1240.py
    - Add field change_date to boatimage
    - Add field change_date to boatmodel
- Alter field boat_name on boatmodel
```

These are new changes to apply

And finally migrate:

```
 heroku run -a boatsproject-eu  python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ boatsproject-eu... up, run.7674 (Free)
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, articles, auth, boats, captcha, contenttypes, easy_thumbnails, reversion, sessions, social_django, testapp
Running migrations:
  Applying articles.0017_auto_20190517_1713... OK
  Applying boats.0026_auto_20190522_1053... OK
  Applying boats.0027_auto_20190530_1536... OK
  Applying reversion.0001_squashed_0004_auto_20160611_1202... OK
  Applying social_django.0001_initial... OK
  Applying social_django.0002_add_related_name... OK
  Applying social_django.0003_alter_email_max_length... OK
  Applying social_django.0004_auto_20160423_0400... OK
  Applying social_django.0005_auto_20160727_2333... OK
  Applying social_django.0006_partial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "social_auth_partial" already exists


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 307, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "social_auth_partial" already exists
```

It it were locally, I could have manually delete migration files and migrate from scratch or delete last migration but what to do on Heroku – I dont know.

Only 1 thing that comes to mind is move code with empty migration folders to GitHub  and deploy from there and ran migration from the initial migration but it seems as overkill kindof.

Would you recommend me some actions to do with this situation?

Thank you

P.S. I have read  this one [Django 1.7 - "No migrations to apply" when run migrate after makemigrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958708/django-1-7-no-migrations-to-apply-when-run-migrate-after-makemigrations)   , tried some – no success, seems like I even deeply buried my way back with this

Shwomigrations

```
 python manage.py showmigrations on ⬢ boatsproject-eu... up, run.1339 (Free)
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
articles
 [X] 0001_squashed_0015_auto_20190513_1722 (15 squashed migrations)
 [X] 0016_auto_20190513_1808
 [X] 0017_auto_20190517_1713
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
boats
 [X] 0001_squashed_0025_auto_20190507_2237 (25 squashed migrations)
 [X] 0026_auto_20190522_1053
 [X] 0027_auto_20190530_1536
captcha
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
easy_thumbnails
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_thumbnaildimensions
reversion
 [X] 0001_squashed_0004_auto_20160611_1202
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
social_django
 [X] 0001_initial (2 squashed migrations)
 [X] 0002_add_related_name (2 squashed migrations)
 [X] 0003_alter_email_max_length (2 squashed migrations)
 [X] 0004_auto_20160423_0400 (2 squashed migrations)
 [X] 0005_auto_20160727_2333 (1 squashed migrations)
 [ ] 0006_partial
 [ ] 0007_code_timestamp
 [ ] 0008_partial_timestamp
testapp
 [X] 0001_initial
PS C:\Users\hardcase1\PycharmProjects\myproject>
```

Comment: You should not be running makemigrations on Heroku, anyway. You run it locally and commit the result.

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman Well, for some reason it doesnt work this way. How django_migrations table on Heroku Postgree would be syncronised with local one this way? Or i do it wrong way perhaps?

Comment: I found a , lets call it final solution here https://gist.github.com/zulhfreelancer/ea140d8ef9292fa9165e. Which is kill heroku database and migrate from scratch. Wrong way, but i stupedly came up only with this idea