# ' No migrations to apply' after Django migration

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I made a new app called 'contact' which I added to installed_apps, but I can't create a table in the SQLite database!

Django version =  3.1

`python manage.py makemigrations contact`

No changes detected in app 'contact'

then for : `python manage.py migrate contact`

Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: (none)
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.

I have tried many solutions proposed by members here but None worked

like checking "init" file existed in migrations folder and it's empty or commands like these :

```
python manage.py migrate --fake contact zero
```

Operations to perform:
Unapply all migrations: contact
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.

```
python manage.py migrate contact --fake-initial
```

Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: (none)
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.

Comment: Junior Django developer here:
Have you tried running "python manage.py makemigrations"? Instead of specifying which model you are trying to migrate.
Also, have you written any models on Contact.models.py file?

Comment: yes, I have tried this before adding app name

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This worked for me;

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname

python manage.py migrate yourappname
```

It turns out adding an extra empty migration forces django to recheck the table and in the process, it noticed the new migrations. There's probably some caching taking place somewhere.

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958708/django-1-7-no-migrations-to-apply-when-run-migrate-after-makemigrations)

Comment: would you provide more explanation on why this worked in your answer

Comment: I'd overlooked this, but it worked for me as well.

Comment: thask a lot!!!!

Comment: I had a similar problem and found that deleting the migrations/__pycache__ directory solved it.

Answer (score -1):

Try not to use the name of your app.

Eg.

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

If don't work. You can do something more risky. Go to the directory of your project. Take the database to another folder. Make the same above commands.