# Heroku No migrations to apply

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm having trouble with my database at Heroku:

I've added some models for my App and whenever I run makemigrations it detects those changes. However when I run migrate it only says no migrations to apply. Please help!

Comment: that is not a big deal some time this happens because maybe table already exits that's why it says no migrations to apply try to run you server if you get any error like no such table than let me know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django 1.7 - "No migrations to apply" when run migrate after makemigrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958708/django-1-7-no-migrations-to-apply-when-run-migrate-after-makemigrations)

Comment: there's no table. the server says programming error: no column"position" exists in clients

Comment: I dont know how to execute the solution and I think it doesn't work on my problem

Comment: okay delete all migration files in migrations folder.

Comment: and than try to run again makemigrations and migrate command

Comment: okay I've deleted it already

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233265/discussion-between-ankit-tiwari-and-tyrone-jasper-galang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'VE FINALLY FIXED IT!!! This is what I did:

First I did a backup Download by heroku pg:backups:restore capture

then heroku pg:backups:restore download
it made a "latest.dump" file

then I used heroku pg:reset
it deleted the recent database of host

then I applied my fixes on my models and forms
new fields has to have "defaults=None" for models with Data you want to preserve (If you won't do this, the merge for this model won't take effect and will be cancelled)

then I run heroku run bash
run python manage.py makemigrations appname
then migrate

and then used "pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h yourDBhost -U yourDBuser -d yourDBname latest.dump" (Your database credentials will be found on your postgresql addon settings) and then type or copy-paste yourDBpassword(from credentials also) to merge the backed up database with the new one with changes

and know it's done and perfectly working!

Comment: Good to know finally you solved your problem.