# Why does Django not see migrations?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to change some field names of Django models, but for some reasons Django does not want to see my migrations. I made sure the following things are properly set up:

- `myApp.apps.MyAppConfig` is added to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py
- A migration folder with an empty `__init__.py` is present in my app folder
- In myApp folder, I also have an empty `__init__.py`

The whole procedure works just fine locally with a SQLite database and I can change field names and run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` to migrate the database. However in production where I use Docker Compose for orchestration and Postgres as database only the first migration works fine. Afterwards when I change any model field name and try to run `docker-compose exec projectname django-admin makemigrations` or `docker-compose exec projectname python manage.py makemigrations` or add the app name behind these commands nothing helps.

Then Postgres can't handle the request, because it doesn't know the new field name:

```
2022-03-11 14:40:22.136 UTC [81] ERROR:  column model_name.new_field_name does not exist at character 357
```

What am I missing here? How can I get Django to migrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I was able to solve this issue by adding a Docker volume for the migrations folder. I believe a lot of times people put their entire code in a persistent volume, which would've also prevented this issue. However at least everything that needs to be persistent (obviously) needs a persistent volume.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues when using version control to submit changes to another environment.

What *probably* happens is that django believes it already made the migration, because of the information that is being passed along when you push those changes. What you need to do is to correct that behavior manually deleting those migrations or, if you don't need to keep information yet, force the migration from the beginning.

You may want to read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#workflow) for future use, and I used [the answers in this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958708/django-1-7-no-migrations-to-apply-when-run-migrate-after-makemigrations) to solve the same issue.

Comment: Hi Cote, thanks for your answer. I don't commit any files from the migrations folder except `__init__.py` to the repository. Where else is this information stored?