# Django migrations not applied

Tags: django, migration

I am trying to do the [portfolio project](https://realpython.com/get-started-with-django-1/) and when doing the migration part, I get this:

Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: projects
Running migrations:
**No migrations to apply.**

What am I doing wrong? I am following the exact steps written on the document

I tried looking on google and could not find any good answers, please help.

Comment: I think the answers on this page will help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958708/django-1-7-no-migrations-to-apply-when-run-migrate-after-makemigrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app name>
python manage.py migrate <app name>
```

Comment: I tried that and I get the same thing as mentioned in the question. When I run the server, I get this message: 'You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.' :(

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/11983208/divya-prakash. The trick is to run the commands all at once and not sequentially. Just copy paste the commands exactly as it on the terminal, not like `python manage.py makemigrations <app name>` first and then `python manage.py migrate <app name>`